# CPU utilization mail alert for any running services in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

i need to get email alert if (top comand) %CPU is above 95% for any current running services can help me for this script…

Thanks

Comment: What do you use for mail? Is `sendmail` installed and configured?

Comment: Above 95% for how long?  When measured over a short enough interval, everything will be 100% at some point or another...